# Karma/Jasmine Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**Edit:** Looks like other people are getting similar errors [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor/issues/148)
**Edit 2:** It seems to be specific to Chrome, as Firefox works.

I had tests that were working and are now getting an error :

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
            at Object.invoke (lib/angular/angular.js:4771:19)
            at lib/angular/angular.js:4578:62
            at forEach (lib/angular/angular.js:325:20)
            at Object.createInjector [as injector] (lib/angular/angular.js:4578:3)
```

I tried creating a simple test, and I believe the issue is when I I am trying to inject templates. I am using **karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor** to compile my templates, and I think it may be that the library is now broken due to changes in dependencies. What would be the best way to verify that this is in fact the issue? I looked at the Git repo and verified that it has a dozen out of date dependencies but this doesn't necessarily mean it's broken.

**Karma.conf**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
        'spec/testData/**/*.js',
        'spec/helpers/bundle/tisfBundle.js',
        'lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'lib/angular/angular.js',
        'lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
        'lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'lib/tisf-angular/build/js/tisf-angular.js',
        'lib/twix/dist/js/twix.js',
        'lib/spin.js/spin.js',
        'lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'spec/app/*Spec.js',
        'spec/app/**/*Spec.js',

        'app/modules/directives/*.js',
        'app/modules/tcm-help-app.js',

        'app/modules/views/home/*.js',
        'app/modules/views/home/**/*.js',
        'app/modules/services/**/*.js',
        'app/modules/directives/**/*.js',

        'app/modules/views/home/*.html',
        'app/modules/directives/**/*.html',

        '**/*.html'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
        'app/modules/views/home/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
        'app/modules/views/home/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
        'app/modules/directives/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        prependPrefix: '/',
        moduleName: 'tcmTemplates'
    },

    reporters: ['spec'],
    specReporter: {
    maxLogLines: 5,
    suppressErrorSummary: true,
    failFast: true
    },

    port: 9876,    

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: false, 

    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

**Sample test**

```
describe('Home', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('tcm-help-ui'));
    beforeEach(module('tcmTemplates')); //test works without this line

    var $homeController, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$controller_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $homeController = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('HomeController', function () {
        var $ctrl;
        beforeEach(function () {
            $ctrl = $homeController('tcmHomeController', {$scope: scope});
        });

        it('should be defined', function() {
            expect($ctrl).toBeDefined();
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide your karma.conf.js file? And maybe the simple test that you are speaking about?

Comment: @JonBlack Added